# PyCharm странно интерпретирует поля для ввода. Без аргументов(текста) в input() выдает ошибки или в текущем случае создает пустой список

Tags: python, pycharm

**UPD: Вообщем проблема решена после обновления PyCharm. Возможно пофиксили какие то недочеты, ибо когды впервые скачал уже возникала такая проблема, думал что особенность питона.**

Собственно хочу понять почему такая проблема возникает. Если я делал код с двумя input() подряд без аргументов то код вообще отказывался работать на вводе второго input(). Ситуации исправлял добавляенный текст внутрь. Но сейчас уже не в какие ворота, почему он мне создает пустые списки?

Первый скриншот: так выглядит результат с пустым input() без текста внутри.

Второй скриншот: Так выглядит корректный результат с заполнеными полями input('enter: ').

[image: Так выглядит результат с пустым input() без текста внутри.]
[image: Так выглядит корректный результат с заполнеными полями input('enter: ').]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых хз, дело не в ошибке в коде, дело видимо в питоне и/или PyCharm. Для начала обнови pycharm (оранжевый символ ^ справа сверху). Потом попробуй изменить env. Для этого нажимаешь на файл, рядом с кнопкой запуск и смотришь пункт Edit Configurations.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да в пишарме дело. Уже который раз этот вопрос задают. причины и временные решения - все есть.